# Show that the sequence $a_{n+2} = \sin(a_{n+1}) + \sin(a_{n})$ with $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ converges to the positive solution of $\sin(x) = 1/2x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was fiddling around with a code to generate the Fibonacci sequence and I tried changing the recursive formula to

$$a_{n+2} = \sin(a_{n+1}) + \sin(a_{n})$$

But keeping $a_1 = a_2 = 1$.

The first terms of the sequence are: $\{1,1,
 1.6829,
 1.8351,
 1.9589,
 1.8908\}$ (four first decimals shown)

After many iterations, the sequence clearly appears to converge to $1.895494267033981\ldots$

By googling this number, I found out it is the only positive solution of

$$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$$

Is it easy to prove that this is true (that the sequence converges to the solution of the equation)? I do not know how trivial or complicated it may be.

Comment: If the sequence converges then it can only converge to one of the solutions to the equation $$x=\sin{(x)}+\sin{(x)}\iff \sin{(x)}=\frac12x$$and heuristically the sequence converges because the sequence $b_n=\alpha-a_n$ where $\sin{(\alpha)}=\alpha/2$ satisfies$$b_{n+2}=\cos{(\alpha)}(b_{n+1}+b_n)+O(b_{n+1}^2)+O(b_n^2)$$so for sufficiently small $b_n$ we can ignore the quadratic terms and the second order linear recurrence solution proves that $b_n\to 0$ and hence $a_n\to\alpha$ as required.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks! I wouldn't think it was that simple. If you'd like to post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Well technically I haven't proven anything so I would wait to see if anyone can provide an analytical proof.